# How long does it take for a Kuwait work visa to be renewed?

Tags: working-visas, kuwait

I'm going to work in Kuwait. I have a work visa, but it has already expired. If I renew the visa, how long will I have to wait for it to be issued?

Comment: The best site for this question is https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ since it is related to your work permit rather than travelling.  You could also ask the issuing authority.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot renew the visa if you are out of Kuwait and its expired. You have to get it renewed in-country.

Therefore, your only recourse is to have a new work visa issued.